# how can i convert many array into one array and count the value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

```
here is my blade template:
```

```
  <tbody>
     @foreach ($meals as $keys=>$meal)
       <tr>
         <td>{{$keys+1}}</td>
         <td>{{$meal->date}}</td>
           @php
             $totalMealArray = [];
             $detailsmeals= json_decode($meal->mealdetails);
             for($y=0; $y<count($detailsmeals->breakfasts); $y++){
                 $totalMealArray[$y] = (int)$detailsmeals->breakfasts[$y] + (int)$detailsmeals->lunchs[$y]+(int)$detailsmeals->dinners[$y];
             };  
             $totalMeals = array($totalMealArray);
             dump($totalMeals);                                     
            @endphp
            @for ($i = 0; $i < count($detailsmeals->breakfasts); $i++)
              <td class="text-center table-primary">{{$detailsmeals->breakfasts[$i]}}</td>
              <td class="text-center table-info">{{$detailsmeals->lunchs[$i]}}</td>
              <td class="text-center table-secondary">{{$detailsmeals->dinners[$i]}}</td>                       
             @endfor                         
          </tr>                      
         @endforeach                  
      </tbody>
```

i want to count three column summation value and then add each row. [blade-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMXxU.jpg).

I made such as Manager column B,L,D summation in one rows. but i cannot get the total rows summation value of role(like  Manager, mate1 etc.)  I got these array output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2j7T.jpg). How can i solve it, Please help me.